# Pipe and underline between ea number

Tags: css, xml, sapui5

so i have a number lets say 19356 i want it to look like 1|9|3|5|6 and it also to all be underlined. Is this possible without breaking the number and adding a pipe and underline? Also it doesn't have to be a pipe as such just a line between the numbers.

Comment: Are those individual number characters wrapped in spans? A code example would be helpful, but if you just have a number string that's unformatted, you'll need javascript.

Comment: Yer its will be a string from a oData model i know i can split it in to single texts with borders or as you say use a javascript and add a | but dont really want to do that.

Comment: Well, perhaps there's someone with more knowledge than I, but I can't think of a creative way to target individual letters within an unformatted string. You can target the first or last character, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution your problem. You can achieve it by extending **sap.m.FormattedText** and handling the functionality as we need as follows.

I will create two files with name **SpecialFormattedText** and **SpecialFormattedTextRenderer** as below.

Here is first class that extends FormattedText and has one property **number** of type int, because you wanted to work with numbers So I choose the int data type.

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/FormattedText"], function (FormattedText) {
    "use strict";
    return FormattedText.extend("SpecialFormattedText", {
        metadata : {
            properties : {
                 number : {
                     type : "int", defaultValue : null
                 }
            }
        },
        setNumber : function(iMumber) {
            this.setProperty("number", iMumber, true);
            this.setProperty("htmlText", this._getUpdatedNumber(iMumber), true);
        },
        _getUpdatedNumber : function(iMumber) {
            return "<U>"+iMumber.toString().match(/.{1}/g).join('|')+"</U>";
        }
    });
});
```

Here I will convert the input as we required and setting to the **htmlText** of **FormattedText** and maintaining the original value in **number**. And you can get the original value by using **getNumber** method provided by **SpecialFormattedText** class object.

And the next important thing is we are writing the renderer in other class named **SpecialFormattedTextRenderer**. In this class we will just call the sap.m.FormattedTextRenderer class renderer method as below.

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/m/FormattedTextRenderer"], function (FormattedTextRenderer) {
    "use strict";
    var SpecialFormattedTextRenderer = {};
    SpecialFormattedTextRenderer.render = function (oRM, oControl) {
        oRM.write("<div");
        FormattedTextRenderer.render(oRM, oControl);
        oRM.write("</div>");
    };
    return SpecialFormattedTextRenderer;
},true);
```